# How to use the same data between two GUI's in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hey guys I am currently working on a homework assignment.  I have two GUI's that I would like to access the same data which will be handled by my other class accountmanager.  I believe I need to make one main class that will call both GUI's and create an accountmanager object.

Once I construct the object, how would I send the information to both GUI classes?

Thanks ahead for your help, I hope I was detailed enough.  I don't really know how to explain it without posting all of the code.

edit

---

Ok I appreciate your replies.  I am stuck at this..

```
    Account Accnt = new Account();
GUI1 gui1 = new GUI1();
GUI2 gui2 = new GUI2();
```

I want to decide what data gets stored for Account Object by using the GUI.  For example, GUI1 opens accounts with a name that the user inputs.  Account assigns an ID number for each account that is opened.  GUI2 can then access information stored for each account by choosing the ID number.

Comment: Can anyone read my edit and give me some advice without using observers?  I think I gotta keep it simple for this assignment since we haven't gone over observers.

Comment: BTW - A 'GUI' should typically contain one `JFrame` and one or more `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instances.  If you are using 2 or more frames, that will cause problems for this use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Create the object, pass it (reference) into both GUIs (either through constructor or a method).

Example:

```
main(){
    Account accnt = new Account();
    // both GUI objects receive the same accnt object
    GUI1 gui1 = new GUI1(accnt);
    GUI2 gui2 = new GUI2(accnt);
    // your code
}

public class GUI1{
    private Account accnt;

    public GUI1(Account accnt){
        this.accnt = accnt;
        // your code
    }
    // your code
}

public class GUI2{
    private Account accnt;

    public GUI2(Account accnt){
        this.accnt = accnt;
        // your code
    }
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the passing it or reference part.  I want to add buttonlisteners to the GUI's to retrieve the data from the user.  If I put the button listeners in the GUI how would they be able to send the data back to the original object to be accessed by the other GUI?

Comment: If both "GUI" objects hold a reference to the same Account object, both GUI objects be able to access/modify the Account object.

If you want to add it from the constructor, add a parameter to your GUI object's constructor. Alternatively create a method for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Have the AccountManager class implement [java.util.Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html).

Have the GUI classes implement [java.util.Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html).

Call [addObserver()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#addObserver%28java.util.Observer%29) on AccountManager for each of the GUI classes.

Call notifyObservers when a change occurs in AccountManager.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to study some design patterns first. You can use [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or you can use [MVC design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which you'll have to learn sooner or later anyway, if you wanna do some more advanced programming...

Just google "[java mvc example](http://www.google.cz/search?q=java%20mvc%20example)" and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's a number of ways to go about this but the way you choose to do it needs to reflect your ability (i.e. your teacher/lecturer/etc. will know if you suddenly implement an Observer Pattern and can't explain what it is). In this particular situation I would go with the Singleton approach, as there isn't a database or anything majorly complex.

A singleton is a class where only one instance of it is created and provides a global point of access to the object.

Here's an example of a singleton class and how you might use one:

```
public final class ExampleSingleton {
    private static ExampleSingleton instance = null;

    private ExampleSingleton() { /*Do not allow instantiation*/ }

    public static ExampleSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ExampleSingleton();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

The above class is using a private constructor which means that you cannot explicity construct an `ExampleSingleton`. This means that to get a singleton object, you would do something like:

```
 ExampleSingleton myObject = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
```

Then to use the object you would reference `myObject` and any methods therein (in this case `sayHello()`.

What this means for you, is that your code can end up looking something like this:

```
public class MyGui1 {
    private ExampleSingleton myData = null;

    public MyGui1() {
        myData = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
    }

    public updateData(. . .) {
        myData.updateData(. . .);
    }

    public retrieveData(. . . ) {
        myData.retrieveData(. . .);
    }
}

public class MyGui2 {
    private ExampleSingleton myData = null;

    public MyGui2() {
        myData = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
    }

    . . . 

    //Do you see where I'm going with this?
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void Main(String args[]) {
        ExampleSingleton myData = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
        myData.setInitialData(. . .);

        MyGui1 = new MyGui1();
        MyGui2 = new MyGui2();

        //Do more stuff here
    }
}
```

Because both GUI objects are using the *same* singleton, the data will always be available to both.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague; there are many ways to go about this, here is one example.

```
public class MyData()
{
   ...my data
}

public class ViewOne extends JFrame
{
   MyData myData = new MyData;
}

public class ViewTwo extends JFrame
{
   MyData myData = new MyData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Create a universally accessible data (i.e. singletons) that the two GUIs can access
2. Pass the data to the GUI

```
    Data theData = new Data();
    GUIObject object1 = new GUIObject();
    GUIObject object2 = new GUIObject();
    object1.setData(data);
    object2.setData(data);
```

Comment: I am along the lines of this but don't really understand the setData portion.  Could you look at my edited question and reply again?  Thank you